# Whether PostSharp log attribute support ansyc meathed and how to use it to write the log to a log file?

Tags: log4net, postsharp

1. I want to know whether the log attribute of Postsharp supports ansyc method?
2. I want to use the log attribute to write log infos to a file.

Can you give me a demo to show me how to write log infos to a file by using log4net?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: You could [try the documentation](http://doc.postsharp.net/logging)

Comment: Yeah.The doc give a sample demo.But I don't know how to plus log4net and write the log to a txt file.

Comment: You can start reading some log4net documentation. And than it is not so hard to write something in a file. Writing to a log file is not a postsharp specific problem...

Answer (score 0):

Log attribute doesn't support async methods. You can apply it to them but it doesn't understand underlying state machine so result could be quite disappointing (e.g. method exit will be logged before first await).

Adding log aspect is easy when you use PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio. Just place the caret over code element identifier (like class name or namespace) and open smart tag (or lightbulb in VS2015), select Add logging... and walk through the wizard. It is pretty straightforward.

PostSharp itself supports only logging to console and trace. As mentioned in comments you can select other backends like log4net or nlog to store log output in files (or anywhere else).

How to configure log4net is well described [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) and how to configure nlog is described [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file).

Comment: Thanks.So It means AOP can't sport async methods.It's terrible.

Comment: In general case, PostSharp now supports advising of async methods. You can see some examples in the [docs](http://doc.postsharp.net/async-methods#apply-to-state-machine). This allows you to create your own logging aspect that understands async state machines. However, the built-in [Log] aspect in PostSharp has not been updated for async yet.

Comment: Thank you.Maybe I can't use AOP to log async methods.I can't know how to work in Roslyn.